# Turkish characters to uppercase

Tags: capitalization

I can't make uppercase of turkish characters like `Giriş` Tex converts it to `GIRIş` instead of `GİRİŞ`.. It's making me crazy.

```
%this is mwe i guess
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\begin{document}
\uppercase{Giriş}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a deficiency in the setup by `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\addto\extrasturkish{%
  \uccode`i=\string"9D \uccode\string"19 = `I
  \lccode\string"9D=`i \lccode`I=\string"19 }
\addto\noextrasturkish{%
  \uccode`i=`I \lccode`I=`i }

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Giriş}

\MakeLowercase{GİRİŞ}
\end{document}
```

It's better to do it this way instead of globally changing the tables.

In the T1 encoding the character "dotless i" is at position `"19` and "dotted I" is at `"9D`.

Comment: my bad, sorry. great answer. even it would be great if someone put this some kind of faq.

Comment: @interlude This should really be addressed by fixing `babel`.

Comment: Note: the problem has long been solved: with version 1.3a of `turkish.ldf`, released 2014-01-14, the correspondence between uppercase and lowercase letters has been fixed.