# How can I improve my Turkish Small Capitals (XeTeX)

Tags: xetex, small-caps

#### Status update

In a private email, Bogusław Jackowski (to whom my sincere thanks) has recognised this as a bug in the TeX Gyre fonts. As the TeX Gyre team are all working hard on another piece of the TeX Gyre project, he cannot commit to a date for fixing this, but his best estimate is sometime next year.

---

[Turkish characters to small caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58102/turkish-characters-to-small-caps) and [Turkish characters to uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/turkish-characters-to-uppercase) attempt to address the tribulations of those of us who need to deal with the dotted letter i/İ, in full-size and small capitals. As far as I can see, all the answers address the `pdftex` engine.

Here's my MWE to illustrate my annoyance:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\Huge
  \textsc{Eb\.ı} \.Incelemesi\\[6pt]
  \textsc{Eb\.{}\kern -0.215em ı} \.Incelemesi
}
\end{document}
```

and here's the output:

[image: PDF output screen capture]

Now, can anyone, please, explain to me:

1. (Curiosity) Why is the dot accent over the B so badly out-of-joint?
2. (Real question) Given that (a) none of my fonts appears to have the TRK feature; (b) although they have a small caps dotted İ, the position in the glyph table varies, and the Unicode code point, of course, is at some random location in the Private Area; and (c) the time I spent hand-tuning the "-0.215em" will almost certainly need to be spent again if I change fonts; then what better and more robust method is there for producing the second line?

---

Further to EGreg's interesting comment, I 'made up' a new MWE, with an extra ı just to emphasize the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
  Script=Latin,
  Language=Turkish,
  ]{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\Huge
  \textsc{Ebiı} İncelemesi\\[6pt]
}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output; the dot is still missing:

[image: More PDF output]

---

So now I'm getting irritated with myself, and I add another option:

```
\setmainfont[%
  Script=Latin,
  Language=Turkish,
  Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps,
  ]{TeX Gyre Adventor}
```

which gives the same result.

Then I switched to Brill, with the same options, and got this:

[image: output from Brill]

which, of course, is not what I want, as EBİ is now all uppercase, not SC.

At which point I'm going to sleep on it. What's the correct behaviour for `Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps`?

Comment: Actually `otfinfo` run over TeX Gyre Adventor claims that the TRK feature is available.

Comment: @Raphink The question is very interesting; what I believe is that the TRK feature is uncorrectly implemented in the TeX Gyre fonts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the implementation of the TRK feature in the TeX Gyre fonts. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Brill}
\setmainlanguage{turkish}
\newfontfamily{\termes}[Language=Turkish]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Ebi} İncemelesi \textsc{ıIiİ}

\termes
\textsc{Ebi} İncemelesi \textsc{ıIiİ}

\end{document}
```

and here's the result

[image]

The log file makes clear that the TRK feature is selected for both fonts:

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'TeXGyreTermes(0)' created for font 'TeX Gyre Termes' with
. options [Language=Turkish].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"TeX Gyre Termes/ICU:script=latn;language=TRK;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"TeX Gyre Termes/ICU:script=latn;language=TRK;+smcp;"

[...]

. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Brill(1)' created for font 'Brill' with options
. [,Language=Turkish].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Brill/ICU:script=latn;language=TRK;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Brill/ICU:script=latn;language=TRK;+smcp;"

[...]
```

---

Here's the relevant part of the interaction between `polyglossia` and `fontspec` (line numbers from `polyglossia.sty`):

```
253 \def\xpg@addfontfeature@lang#1#2{% #1 is langtag, #2 is langname
254   % Turkish is a special case: tag can be TRK or TUR
255   \edef\tmp@Turkish{Turkish}%
256   \edef\tmp@@langname{#2}%
257   %  \ifstrequal{#2}{Turkish}%
258   \ifx\tmp@@langname\tmp@Turkish
259     \fontspec_if_language:nTF {TRK}%
260       {\addfontfeature{Language=Turkish}}%
261       {\fontspec_if_language:nTF {TUR}%
262         {\addfontfeature{Language=Turkish}}%
263         {}}%
264     % else not Turkish
265   \else
266      \edef\tmp@@langparam{Language=#2}%
267      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\fontspec_if_language:nTF \expandafter{#1}%
268       {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addfontfeature\expandafter{\tmp@@langparam}}%
269       {}%
270   \fi
271 }
```

Essentially, the `Language=...` option is passed to the defined font families (and `fontspec` creates a new one, as results from the log file reported above). The fact that Turkish is treated in a special way is a happy coincidence.

If you're not using `polyglossia`, then you should define a font family for Turkish anyway, or `\textsc` won't give the expected result on "i" when a non-Turkish language is involved.

Comment: It looks like the Latin Modern open type fonts may suffer from the same problem. I've emailed Bogusław for an opinion on the TeX Gyre ¿problem?...

Comment: I have also emailed [Michael Everson](http://www.evertype.com/alphabets/). His documentation of the Turkish alphabet appears to be missing «Capital I with Dot Above»; I wonder if that led the TeX Gyre team astray?

Answer (score 2):

The `fontspec` accent code looks a bit suspect to me.

if you drop back to the classic TeX accent command but using the dot accent from Unicode position things look a bit better. The alignment still seems slightly off for the full size I.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\def\dotabove#1{{\accent729 #1}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}

\Huge
  \textsc{Eb\.ı} \.Incelemesi


  \textsc{Eb\.{}\kern -0.215em ı} \.Incelemesi

  \textsc{Eb\dotabove ı} \dotabove Incelemesi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fontspec itself does not do accent positioning (or any rendering at all, for that matter), it merely passes font names and requested feature to the engine. As for accent positioning, the font has to supply needed information on how to properly position the marks and if the font lacks such info the glyphs will be just laid as is, no `\accent` like positioning is attempt.

Comment: Ah interesting. Still it shows a possible workaround to use `\accent` for accent/base/font combinations for which the font doesn't supply accurate metrics.

Comment: David, thank you for some additional insight. In the end, @egreg got the prize, simply because his answer addressed my initial concerns more directly.

Comment: That's OK @egreg needed the points anyway:-)