# Problem, uppercase header in an other language (Turkish)

Tags: header-footer, languages, capitalization

The part of my MWE preamble

```
....

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\nouppercase{Kısım \thesection{}}\quad\textcolor{orange}{$\blacksquare$}\quad}\textit{\rightmark}\quad\quad\textcolor{blue}{\textbf\thepage}}%
\fancyhead[LE]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf\thepage}\textbf{\quad\quad\nouppercase{Bölüm{ }\thechapter\quad\textcolor{orange}{$\blacksquare$}\quad}}\textit{\leftmark}}%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}
....
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textit{İçindekiler}}
....
```

No uppercase, no problem in Chapter names
[image]

but uppercase problem in headers
[image]

It doesn't İÇ**I**NDEK**I**LER. It does İÇİNDEKİLER. As if, this problem seems like only i .

I find another same question. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Note: İ is uppercase of i and ı is lowercase of I in my language (Turkish).

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/turkish-characters-to-uppercase ?

Comment: @egreg, I am checking.

Comment: @egreg, question is [CLOSED].

Comment: Happy to have helped!