# Turkish characters to uppercase then another problem

Tags: graphics, errors, babel

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\addto\extrasturkish{%
  \uccode`i=\string"9D \uccode\string"19 = `I
  \lccode\string"9D=`i \lccode`I=\string"19 }
\addto\noextrasturkish{%
  \uccode`i=`I \lccode`I=`i }

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textit{İçindekiler}}

\begin{document}

%....
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Map.png}
\caption{Map}
\end{figure}
%....
\end{document}
```

And **Missing number, treated as zero** in **\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Map.png}**

I find another same question. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Related to: [Turkish characters to uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/turkish-characters-to-uppercase)

Related to: [Problem, uppercase header in an other language (Turkish)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220329/problem-uppercase-header-in-an-other-language-turkish)

Comment: Also this has already been discussed: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/usepackageturkishbabel-and-includegraphics-inconcistency

Comment: @egreg, This problem is [CLOSED], too. Also, I would be more than honored to have you here, If you ever have a chance
to visit my city, Izmir.

Comment: It's a very nice city, I believe. :)